# С помощью Notepad++ удалить код внутри

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть следующие строки:

```
бла-бла-бла `href="860.html"` бла-бла-бла
бла-бла-бла `href="58.html"` бла-бла-бла
бла-бла-бла `href="844.html"` бла-бла-бла
бла-бла-бла `href="850.html"` бла-бла-бла
```

Хочу заменить всё то, что между `" "`

Помогите, будьте так любезны!

Comment: href=".*.html" неподходит... выделяет всю строку....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Найти: **`(href=")[^"]*`**
- Заменить на: `$1мойтекст`
- Режим поиска: *Регуляр. выражен.*

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я благодарен тебе, только одно но, последний знак " не выделяется

Comment: @prostporenb Так не было задачи его выделять. Просили удалить всё что между. Уточните вопрос.